# moving a div within a div on resize

Tags: jquery

I've got this almost working on a site I'm doing at the moment but not quite.

The idea is to have the image at the top and on the right on a laptop but move to half way down the section if smaller than 860px and back to the top if the window becomes larger than 860px so on page load and window resize basically.

The page Im working on is here...

https://wordpress-232564-2098483.cloudwaysapps.com/service/mediumship-development/

My jquery code is as below...

```
(function($) {

var minWidth = 860; 

// on page load
$(document).ready(function(){

    var wi = $(window).width();
    
    // if width is less than 860
    if (wi <= minWidth) {
        $('.content-cont').each((i, el) => {
          let $p = $(el).find('p');
          let mid = Math.floor($p.length / 2);

          $('.media-cont',el).insertBefore($p.eq(mid)); // or use the eq here too
          
        });  

    // if width is more than 860        
    } else {
        
        $('.content-cont').each((i, el) => {
          
         $('.media-cont',el).insertBefore(first($('h2'))); // or use the eq here too
          
        });  
        
    }
});


$(window).resize(function() {
    
    //as window resizes
    var wi = $(window).width();    

    // if width is less than 860    
    if (wi <= minWidth) {
        // Inserts image halfway down section
        $('.content-cont').each((i, el) => {
          let $p = $(el).find('p');
          let mid = Math.floor($p.length / 2);

          $('.media-cont',el).insertBefore($p.eq(mid)); // or use the eq here too
          //$('.media-cont').addClass('media-cont-mob');
        });  
    } else {
        // Inserts image back at the top
        $('.content-cont').each((i, el) => {

         $('.media-cont',el).insertBefore(first($('h2'))); // or use the eq here too
        });  
    }
});   


})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Why not use ```css``` media queries?

Comment: Im not sure that that would acheive what im looking to do

Comment: Can you share an image/mockup of both results you are after.